# Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException ./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON

Tags: magento2

i got this error while doing docker-magento project setup with this command: "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/onelinesetup | bash -s -- magento.test 2.4.6 community"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your host `~/.composer/auth.json` file is invalid or corrupt, can you try removing that file or making it contain an empty object `{}` and trying again?

Source: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/506

Btw, since Magento 2.4.6-p1 was released, I recommend you install it instead of 2.4.6.

`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/onelinesetup | bash -s -- magento.test 2.4.6-p1 community`